# How to use the Model in a MVP architecture, when working with multiple datasources

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, user-interface, architecture, mvp

Now it seems like people like to use the MVP pattern in a bit different ways, some prefer the view to be totally unaware of the model and lets the presenter "feed" the data, while some prefer to just give the model to the view and let the view read its data directly from the model. Personally, I prefer the latter.

When reading up on MVP, it seems like all the examples concentrate on more or less CRUD views that work with one type of data. In the real world though, we have views that work with multiple datasources. For example, let's say we have a settings view that works with different type of data, such as SystemSettings, WorkflowSettings and UserSettings (let's not argue about UX, this is just for the sake of an example).

My first question is, how do you define "a model" for a view that works with multiple data sources? I mean, does your view have methods for setting the different "model" (setSystemSettings(), setWorkflowSettings(),...) or do you wrap the actual domain models inside of a DTO and just have a simple setModel(settingsDto) method in your view?

Comment: Model is a layer (with which you would interact through *services*, just like in other MVC-inspired patterns, which then in turn deal with interaction between *domain objects* and storage abstractions). And you would not define "for view" anything. The whole point of [MVP pattern](http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf) is that the data is provided to the view by presenter.

Comment: In the doplhin-smalltalk definition of the MVP pattern, the Model is typically the domain model, living in the domain layer. Regardless if you consider the model a layer or something else, you might have a view that handles multiple type of data. My question was, how do you handle that, do you wrap multiple Domain Models into one object that is given to the view or does your view handle multiple Domain Models directly?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the 'model' is abstract. I now view the model as 'anything the Presenter needs to get its job done'.

So, given your example, my approach might be to define my model as a RepositoryFactory that allows my presenter to create the appropriate repositories it needs to get its data.

This still allows for unit testing, too.